# Get error: permission denied when building docker image using jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I configed a jenkins pipeline to build a project that get from github. But I got an error at step 2 - Build image. Then, I tried to add user admin (of jenkins) to group "docker", and I can run build command successfully without error when login by user admin in the kubernetes master vm, however still error with jenkins. I used blueocean plugin for creating the pipeline. Do you know how to fix this ?

[image]

UPDATE: Please see my jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {

  environment {
    registry = "192.168.64.162:5000/justme/myweb"
    dockerImage = ""
  }

  agent any

  stages {

    stage('Checkout Source') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/taibc/playjenkins.git'        
      }
    }

    stage('Build image') {      
      steps{

        script {
          dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Push Image') {
      steps{
        script {
          docker.withRegistry( "" ) {
            dockerImage.push()
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy App') {
      steps {
        script {
          kubernetesDeploy(configs: "myweb.yaml", kubeconfigId: "mykubeconfig")
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: could you run `who am i` before the docker build command in jenkins? what's the output?

Comment: How can I do that  ? Here my script: pipeline {

  environment {
    registry = "192.168.64.162:5000/justme/myweb"
    dockerImage = ""
  }

  agent any

  stages {

    stage('Checkout Source') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/taibc/playjenkins.git'        
      }
    }
    
    stage('Build image') {      
      steps{
        script {
          dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
        }
      }
    }

    
  }

}

Comment: @BMW: I tried to use "who am i" and get this message: + who am I

/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/playjenkins_master@tmp/durable-31f77306/script.sh: line 1: who: not found

Comment: @Rob: Yes, sorry about that. Thank you

Comment: It's "whoami" - no spaces

Comment: @taleodor: Still command not found

Comment: @all: I think it is because of my jenkins setup. Before, I tried to install jenkins on kubernetes cluster with agent service. When I use a standalone jenkins server, I don't get this error.

Comment: Please follow the `jenkinsfile` usage (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/) to add a stage with shell command before docker build, the shell command could be `who am i` or `whoami`, depends on the linux system. If you can't make it work, try to google it for help for common linux commands first.

Comment: I tried to re-install jenkins on another computer and then overcome this problem. But, I got another error: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cd-plugin/issues/122

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by installing Jenkins to another server (not belong to kubernetes cluster). But, I got another problem when deploying app as the link: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cd-plugin/issues/122

Here my yaml file

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myweb
  name: myweb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myweb
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 192.168.94.162:5000/justme/myweb:1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: myweb

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myweb
  name: myweb
spec:
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32223
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: myweb
  type: NodePort
```

Here my jenkinsscript

```
pipeline {

  environment {
    registry = "192.168.94.162:5000/justme/myweb"
    dockerImage = ""
  }

  agent any

  stages {

    stage('Checkout Source') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/taibc/playjenkins.git'        
      }
    }

    stage('Build image') {      
      steps{

        script {
          dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Push Image') {
      steps{
        script {
          docker.withRegistry( "" ) {
            dockerImage.push()
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy App') {
      steps {
        script {
          kubernetesDeploy(configs: "myweb.yaml", kubeconfigId: "mykubeconfig")
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: After I change apiVersion to apps/v1 the problem has resolved !